# rails_admin and cancancan undefined method `accessible_by' for Product:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, rails-admin, cancancan

I am new to ruby-on-rails and i am looking for a way to have my rails_admin dashboard accessible only by superadmin users. I discovered that the rails_admin gem is fully compatible with another gem: cancancan, used for managing authorizations.

I followed this guide: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancancan to configure rails_admin properly, and this is the result:

**config/initializers/rails_admin.rb**:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  # == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  # == CancanCan ==
  config.authorize_with :cancancan

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app
  end
end
```

**app/models/ability.rb**:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    can :read, :all

    if user.superadmin_role?
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :read, :dashboard
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.admin_role? 
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

When i created the project, i skipped active-records.
For now, the only scaffold i made was for a class called Product.

I keep getting this error when navigating to localhost:3000/admin:

```
NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard

undefined method `accessible_by' for Product:Class
```

I cannot figure out where and how to define this "accessible_by" method. Moreover, i found that on this link https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Fetching-Records, is told that NOT using active records requires a model adapter.

I'm using on MacOS 11.15.6 and:

- Rails 6.0.2
- Rails_admin 2.0.2
- Cancancan 3.0.2
- Mongoid 7.0.5

Can someone help me understanding what am i doing wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: What is the complete stack trace for the error?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan-mongoid ?

Comment: @D.SM Thanks for your comments, i've solved the problem faster that i thought. I've found the cancancan-mongoid gem searching for solutions online, as you also suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got it!

I solved the problem with these steps:

- FIRST OF ALL: STOP `rails server` IF CURRENTLY RUNNING
- Install the `cancancan-mongoid` gem. Simply type `gem 'cancancan-mongoid'` in your Gemfile, UNDER the existing declaration of the cancancan gem. Then run `bundle install`.
  I referred to this page: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan-mongoid
- Check that the order of the gems in your Gemfile looks like this:

```
mongoid
cancancan
cancancan-mongoid
rails_admin
```

The first three steps should solve the problem, but if it persists, proceed with this last step:

- Create a new file called `cancan_mongoid.rb` and place it in your `config/initializers` folder, then paste the full code shown here: https://gist.github.com/bowsersenior/561639

This worked for me! :)